# Inadequate Ecmascript-6 / es6 support for enide / eclipse "Unexpected token" for import / export

Tags: node.js, eclipse, ecmascript-6, enide, unexpected-token

I've installed enide studio 2015 that supports es6, so this error shouldn't appear?
How do I get rid of these error messages?

[image]

Comment: You can't use `import`/`export` in Node.js (yet)...

Comment: Why is it standard in emberjs then? https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.10.0/tutorial/ember-cli/

Answer (score 0):

From #node.js

> While ES6 provides syntax for import/export, it currently *does
>   nothing*, anywhere, because the loader spec is not finished (
>   https://github.com/whatwg/loader ). ES6 Modules are not yet a thing;
>   they do not yet exist. !babel simply transpiles import/export to
>   `require`, which is not guaranteed to work once the loader is
>   finished. Use CommonJS modules for now